# Show Hide Div Menu Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem using show/hide div and it works well on desktop view.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
            // Optional code to hide all divs
            $("#section-intro").show();
            $("#section-about-us").hide();
            $("#section-what-we-do").hide();
            $("#section-oil-gas").hide();
            $("#section-infrastructure").hide();
            $("#section-mining").hide();
            $("#section-constructions").hide();
            $("#section-logistics").hide();
            $("#section-main-services").hide();
            $("#section-business-approach").hide();
            $("#section-resources").hide();
            $("#section-contact-us").hide();
            // Show chosen section from menu, and hide all others sections
            $('.hidecontent').click(function(){
                jQuery('.showHideDiv').hide();
                var id = $(this).attr("href");
                $(id).show();
            });
            // Show chosen section from intro, and hide all others sections
            $('.footerlinks a').click(function(){
                jQuery('.showHideDiv').hide();
                var id = $(this).attr("href");
                $(id).show();
            });
   });
})(jQuery);
```

I have added a class in a Wordpress menu `".hidecontent"` and it gets the href url `"#somediv"` and displays that and hides the previous section. It works well.

Problem is when it gets to tablet/mobile view it doesn't work anymore.

My logic is saying that it has something to do with the responsive mobile view when you have to press the button and dropdown shows but I cannot figure it out. I have tried every class and nothing works and it should work anyway.

Anybody have an idea about it? I have tried for the last few hours to get this working.

You can see it live here: http://euro.greekmedia.ro/

Thank you.

//EDIT
HTML

```
<div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="65" data-fixed-height="40" style="padding-left: 238px;">
<nav id="top-menu-nav">
    <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
        <li id="menu-item-46532" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46532"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-about-us">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46533" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46533"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-what-we-do">What we do</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46534" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-46534"><a href="#">Industries</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-46535" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46535"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-oil-gas">Oil &amp; Gas</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-46536" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46536"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-infrastructure">Infrastructure</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-46537" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46537"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-mining">Mining</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-46604" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46604"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-constructions">Constructions</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-46603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46603"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-logistics">Logistics</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46538" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46538"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-main-services">Main services</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46539" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46539"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-business-approach">Business approach</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46541" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46541"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-resources">Resources</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46542" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46542"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-contact-us">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>




<div id="et_mobile_nav_menu">
    <div class="mobile_nav closed">
        <span class="select_page">Select Page</span>
        <span class="mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle"></span>
        <ul id="mobile_menu" class="et_mobile_menu">
            <li id="menu-item-46532" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46532 et_first_mobile_item"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-about-us">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46533" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46533"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-what-we-do">What we do</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46534" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-46534"><a href="#">Industries</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-46535" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46535"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-oil-gas">Oil &amp; Gas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-46536" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46536"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-infrastructure">Infrastructure</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-46537" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46537"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-mining">Mining</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-46604" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46604"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-constructions">Constructions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-46603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46603"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-logistics">Logistics</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46538" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46538"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-main-services">Main services</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46539" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46539"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-business-approach">Business approach</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46541" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46541"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-resources">Resources</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-46542" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46542"><a class="hidecontent" href="#section-contact-us">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

would you like to give me the html to see better the panorama

so I see these happening as id the href but you need the `#` so jquery recognizes it

something like that

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
 $(function() {
        // Optional code to hide all divs
        $("#section-intro").show();
        $("#section-about-us").hide();
        $("#section-what-we-do").hide();
        $("#section-oil-gas").hide();
        $("#section-infrastructure").hide();
        $("#section-mining").hide();
        $("#section-constructions").hide();
        $("#section-logistics").hide();
        $("#section-main-services").hide();
        $("#section-business-approach").hide();
        $("#section-resources").hide();
        $("#section-contact-us").hide();
        // Show chosen section from menu, and hide all others sections
        $('.hidecontent').click(function(){
            jQuery('.showHideDiv').hide();
            var id = $(this).attr("href");
            $('#'+id).show();
        });
        // Show chosen section from intro, and hide all others sections
        $('.footerlinks a').click(function(){
            jQuery('.showHideDiv').hide();
            var id = $(this).attr("href");
            $('#'+id).show();
        });
```

});
})(jQuery);

Comment: Hi, i've tryed your code, dosnt work also it dosnt work on website if i add a #, because it already gets it once it gets the href url. I cant give you html because its on divi and you have url up in first post. Thanks for help!

Comment: test only using `fadeIn ()` and `fadeOut` instead of` show () `and` hide () `

Comment: Still the same. The javascript dosnt run on mobile menu. I've added html in post, maybe you can figure it out this way.

Comment: I think it has something to do with clicking, because i have to click on hamburget icon and after click on the link to get me to the section. Any ideas on it?

Comment: try using `event.preventDefault ()` so that the click functionality does not run on devices

Comment: It still dosnt work. It has something to do with the menu, because i have also in footer same idea, but there you dont have to press hamburger icon to see the links.

Comment: I already know where the problem is with the `on` method instead of normal click

Comment: And what can i do about it? do you know how can i fix it?